# Can I use Tails on a device that is already running Orbot?

Tags: tails, orbot

Can I use Tails on a device that is already running Orbot? Or should I disable Orbot first?

Answer (score 2):

Your question suggests a bit of confusion, so I'll try to clarify.

- [Orbot](https://guardianproject.info/apps/orbot/) is an app for Android phones that connects to the Tor
  network. You can then set other apps on your phone to use Orbot to
  route their traffic through Tor before entering the wider internet.
  It allows mobile phone users to access the web/messaging/email
  without being monitored or blocked by their mobile internet service
  provider.
- [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) is a live operating system meant to run on a
  desktop/laptop computer from a DVD, USB stick, or SD card. When using
  Tails ALL connections to the Internet are routed through the Tor
  network.

So, it's not really possible to "use Tails on a device that is already running Orbot" because:

1. They're built for different devices
2. Tails is a full Operating System whilst Orbot is an App built to run within the Android Operating System

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I am new at Tor so please bare with me. I don't want there to be any of my activities recorded on my android tablet memory. So can I use a Tails loaded SD card on my android tablet? Thhanks

Comment: no you can't... as explained: within android you can just use Orbot and not Tails!